# Removing from MEF container

Tags: c#, mef

This question seems to have been asked several times, but I have yet to find any answer that actually works.  Very simply, how do I remove something from a MEF container.

Even the code shown here https://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime under AddPart/RemovePart doesn't work as it won't compile as it is listed.  The code shows this:

```
    var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    var root = new Root();

    // add external part
    container.ComposeParts(root);

    // ... use the composed root instance

    // removes external part
    batch = new CompositionBatch();
    batch.RemovePart(root);
    container.Compose(batch);
```

This won't compile because the call to RemovePart requires a ComposablePart which root is clearly not.  Other simple examples show how to create the part and remove the part, but a reference to the created part (as ComposablePart) is remembered so the removal just uses that reference.  I don't want to keep a reference to each part in the container whenever they are created, I just want to remove a part from the container at any arbitrary point in my application without having to keep a reference to it throughout.

Here is what I am trying to do using the exact same pattern listed in the documentation linked above:

```
public class Program
{
    [Import]
    private IClass myClass;

    public Program()
    {
        var container = new CompositionContainer(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        container.ComposeParts(this);

        var partToRemove = container.GetExport<IClass>();

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.RemovePart(partToRemove);
        container.Compose(batch);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following compilation error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Lazy' to
>   'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePart' C:\Users\irbldr.CORP\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs

Which is exactly the same error I get if I use the code directly from the documentation linked above.

Is there no way to simply remove something from the MEF container?

Comment: True, that was a dead end. Sorry.

Comment: What about the CompositionContainer.ReleaseExport and ReleaseExports overloads?

Comment: ReleaseExport(s) just calls IDisposable on the part.  If the part does not implement IDisposable, it does nothing and the container remains unchanged after the call.

Answer (score 0):

This link could be helpful: [How do I get MEF to recompose when I change a part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785801/how-do-i-get-mef-to-recompose-when-i-change-a-part)

But long story short: you can remove from MEF an instance, but you cannot remove an export definition without to drop the complete catalog, recompose and filter it (simply not add something).